# JasperException when deploy on Amazon server

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat

I deployed java web application on my local servers it worked fine but when I deploy on amazon server it give me this exception:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

I use Java 7, Servlet 3.0,Tomcat 7.0.52.

Comment: Could you post full stack trace? The root cause is over there...